# Send information to another form c#

Tags: c#, forms

I have an application that uploads files to a server, but when I press upload it freezes until it is done, so I was thinking to make another form pop up that says uploading and does all of the uploading on that form nested of freezing that main form. But to do this I need to be able to send the selected information to that other form.

I have tried using a BackgroundWorker but that doesn't work, the form still freezes.

Comment: Would you please post some code?

Comment: I think you could define an event that fires when it is uploading a file. You could also use DoEvents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why its freezing is because you are doing uploading on the same thread as the GUI or main thread.
You could create a worker thread to handle the working of the uploading so the GUI doesn't lock while processing the upload.

Example:

```
    private void uploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object[] params = new object[] { "your file what ever type this is a generic example"};
        Thread uploadThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(processUpload));
        uploadThread.IsBackground = true;
        uploadThread.Start(params);
    }

    private void processUpload(object params){
       // do upload logic here 
       object[] _params = (object[])params;
       string s = _params[0].ToString();
    }
```

Passing information from one form to another is straight forward, but this form will also result in a lock while processing. If that's what you want to do then just create a constructor to take a param for whatever you'd like to pass. Then call it accordingly.

```
private string something = null;

public MySecondForm(string Something){
  this.something = Something;
  MessageBox.Show(this.something);
}

// Call this in the parent form 
MySecondForm mySecondForm = new MySecondForm("hello world");
mySecondForm.Show();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient_members(VS.80).aspx) class, you can use [UploadFileAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadfileasync(VS.80).aspx) method. Also you can pass some information from one form to another as follows.

**Form2**

Add a simple constructor to Form2.

```
public Form2(string path) { // ... }
```

**Form1**

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2("Path");
```

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look at this example on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/progressdialog.aspx) for some implementation tips.